# Bisection Method number of steps for convergence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

For the bisection method, determine the formula
$$n \geq \frac{\log(b_0-a_0)-\log(\epsilon)}{\log(2)}-1$$
for the number of steps to guarantee that $|{r-c_n}| < \epsilon.$

This is one of the questions from my numerical analysis class. I understand how to use the bisection method, but I don't understand the analysis of the method or how to start deriving an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with an interval $(a_0,b_0)$ which contains the root, so the error in the root is at most $\frac 12(b_0-a_0)$  Each step shrinks the interval by a factor $2$, so the error after $n$ steps is $\frac 1{2^{n+1}}(b_0-a_0)$  You need to solve $\frac 1{2^{n+1}}(b_0-a_0)\lt \epsilon$ for $n$

Comment: can you explain why it's $2^{n+1}$ and not just $2^n$?

Comment: Because I already had one factor of $\frac 12$ at the start.  After one step you have $\frac 14$. This assumes you report the root (when you quit) as the midpoint of the interval.

Comment: makes sense.. thank you for your explanation.